# MongoDB - Sub document search does not work

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I have a collection called `variants` with its `specifications` as a sub document. Searching for variants with dot notation works for me (but does not use index), whereas using sub document format returns zero results (but utilizes the index). What did I do wrong?

```
> db.variants.getIndexes();
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "automobile.variants",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "specifications" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "automobile.variants",
        "name" : "specifications_1"
    }
]
> db.variants.find({"specifications" : { "Body" : "SUV" }}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor specifications_1",
    "nscanned" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "n" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "specifications" : [
            [
                {
                    "Body" : "SUV"
                },
                {
                    "Body" : "SUV"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
> db.variants.find({"specifications.Body" : "SUV" }).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "nscanned" : 787,
    "nscannedObjects" : 787,
    "n" : 176,
    "millis" : 0,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have put the index on the subdocument itself.

When you do this MongoDB indexes the elements of the array, as such if you were to have:

```
{
    Specifications: [
        {Body: 'SUV'}
    ]
}
```

MongoDB could use an index if you queried:

```
db.col.find({Specifications: {Body: 'SUV'}})
```

Since that matches the element but it cannot query by the parts of that subdocument.

If you wish to query by the parts of the subdocument using an index you should index those parts, i.e.:

```
ensureIndex({Specifications.body: 1})
```

Comment: Thank, but I cannot create the index `Specifications.body`, because there are at least 50 specifications for each variant. What change should I make so that a query for variants with a list of specifications (for example `{Body: 'SUV', Capacity : 4}` will use the index?

Comment: @JoyceBabu Do you really need to use an index for all of them or just for the most selective fields?

Comment: I will be querying for at least 10 of those specifications. Should I create a compound index all of them?

Comment: @JoyceBabu It is hard to say without designing it myself. I will go with yes on this one but with a word of caution that the index might be sizeable on that front. You might find better performance letting some fields hit the document

Comment: The final database size will be small (< 10000 entries). Does it make sense to use index? Will creating an index provide any performance advantage for a db of such a small size?

Comment: @JoyceBabu Yes it should mean the index size should be relatively small and easy to store due to the number of documents you will have

Answer (score 1):

You should have an index on the exact field you will make the query, in this case `specifications.Body`. In your first query since you have an index on specifications field the query uses the index, but it is not valid according to your schema.

Comment: Thank, but I cannot create the index `Specifications.body`, because there are at least 50 specifications for each variant. What change should I make so that a query for variants with a list of specifications (for example `{Body: 'SUV', Capacity : 4}` will use the index?

Comment: Then you need to have a composite index on the fields that you will query on. Be careful that in composite indexes the order of the query is important. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-compound

Comment: Is there any schema modification that I can make for faster searching? For example, change `{Specifications : {Body: "SUV"}}` to `{Specification : [ {Body: "SUV"} ]}`

Comment: Well this might help you actually as for array elements mongodb will create a record on index for each element. In this case for {Body: "SUV"} and {Body: "SVN"} there will be two different records in index and you will able to make fast search.